# PC can't post, boots 1/5 times on average

Tags: boot, memory, hardware-failure, post

I have run through the entire checklist of possible issues with PC startup, looking for that little extra help to resolve it. The PC is used approximately 2 years but the problem started occurring about 4 months ago.

TLDR: Pressing the power button manages to power the PC's components, the GPU lights up, fans spin, processor is running but no picture is displayed, the pc manages to boot after a couple of restarts and runs perfectly smooth with no issues/blue screens/random restarts. Tested without any mouse/usb/keyboards connected, single monitor and dual monitor also does not affect this.

I have encountered similar issues and managed to resolve them by switching the ram sticks with new ones, but this time that didn't fix it.

Should I purchase dual channel ram 2x8gb instead of this one, or could this be a PSU issue?

```
PC:
Motherboard: Asus h110m-cs
CPU: Intel i7-7700
CPU Fan: Arctic Cooling Freezer i11 500
GPU: GTX 1070 
RAM: Apacer 16GB DDR4 2133MHz SODIMM (Single Stick)
```

- I have disassembled and assembled all of the components back together to no avail.
- Tested individual hard drive and SSD with different OS, this is definitely a hardware issue.
- No heat issues and the PC runs completely fine once it manages to boot.
- Cmos battery replaced
- Fast boot has been disabled
- Has not been tested with different ram as I have no ddr4 ram spare to check
- Have not tried a different power supply for the same reason.

Comment: You have started down the proper path - it's hard to tell which component is failing without spares of all of the components.  RAM, motherboard, or CPU seems most likely.  Also try just the video port on the motherboard in case the video card is faulty.  Please edit the Question with the answer : is this a new PC or did it stop working?

Comment: I did try with and without the video card in place and there seem to be no changes.